# Encountering problems while trying to deploy a Flask application on a Windows server

Tags: python, json, windows, flask, server

I am building a chatbot using an API. I have created a Flask application in which I stored HTML and CSS files in the "templates" and "static" folders, respectively. To call the API, I am using a JSON file stored as "cookies.json". The issue I'm facing is that when I run this code on a Windows server locally, it works fine. However, when I deploy it on IIS using wfastcgi, the chatbot is working, but it doesn't provide any responses. The chatbot relies on the API from the JSON file to generate responses. Could you please advise me on how to fix this issue?

.................................................

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.